# actionscript bitmap draw with transform.matrix and rectangle.bounds

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, displayobject

I am trying to get a partial bitmap from an object but I am getting different values from:

```
object.transform.matrix.tx and object.transform.matrix.ty
```

v/s

```
object.getBounds(object.parent).x and object.getBounds(object.parent).y
```

I am not sure which ones should I use while drawing the bitmapdata:

```
bitmapdata.draw(object, <matrix>);
```

To add the a,b,c,d components of matrix are 1,0,0,1 (or identity). So Can someone explain in which scenarios are matrix.tx and matrix.ty different from bounds coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

`object.transform.matrix.tx` is equals to `object.x` if no other transformation is applied (same for `y`). If you draw something to the *negative* coordinates, the `x` and `y` properties of `object` don't change.

```
object.x = 300;
object.y = 300;
object.graphics.beginFill(0);
object.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,100);
```

The *bounding rect* of the circle drawn in this example would start at `-100,-100` but the object's center is still at `300,300` in the parent's coordinate space. Now `getBounds` refers to the area of the object. The area's coordinates are converted to the parent's space and happen to be `200,200`.

---

When are matrix translations and bounds in the parent's coordinate space different?
Almost always, they are only the same if the object's bound (in it's own coordinate space) start at `0,0`.

---

This is partly covered by the [example of `getBounds` in the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#getBounds%28%29). I can't tell you which one should use, it depends on where you need to draw the object, but you haven't mentioned the desired position.

Comment: Hmm interesting. In my case the x and y properties of object were same as getBounds but different than tranform.matrix and as mentioned there was no other transformation. Also the object was a textField so I don't understand how can there be a negative coordinate.